# path is also the name of a node core module

Tags: node.js, gulp

I've just got back into node after a few months, and I'm a bit hazy on what I'm doing

I updated npm, node and gulp. My gulp file seems to work, but I just went to install [gulp-compile-handlebars](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-compile-handlebars) but I get the following:

```
Cooldude-MacBook-Air:_overlay cooldude$ sudo npm install --save-dev gulp-compile-handlebars
Password:
npm WARN package.json path@0.4.9 path is also the name of a node core module.
gulp-compile-handlebars@0.2.0 node_modules/gulp-compile-handlebars
├── through2@0.4.2 (readable-stream@1.0.27-1, xtend@2.1.2)
└── handlebars@2.0.0-alpha.4 (optimist@0.3.7, uglify-js@2.3.6)
Cooldude-MacBook-Air:_overlay cooldude$ ls
gulpfile.js.old node_modules    src
```

I've not seen this before - what should I do to fix this?

Comment: Is your module named path in the package.json file?

Comment: Ah I've somehow lost my project package file. That is definately a clue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not due to the `gulp-compile-handlebars` module since he has (and none of it's dependencies) no call to the `path` module.

I think that you have directly in the `package.json` of your project a reference to the `path` `dependency` that you need to remove because this is now a core module, so you don't have to put it in the `dependencies` of your project.

If it's not referenced, it certainly means that one of your `dependencies` has the `path` `dependency`. You can't do anything about that (expect a PR or an issue on the repo if available).

By the way it's just a Warning npm shows you, not an error so don't need to worry about that.